# Firebase AuthStateListener not working

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a mail verifying activity on my app. Whenever any user register to app, then go to mailverify activity. User can minimize the app and go to the mail Account and verify mail id. My problem is user didn't goes to home activity after verify the mail account. How did it possible.?

My code snippet is..

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}


firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified()) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MailVerify.this, userHome.class));
            Toast.makeText(MailVerify.this, "Account Verified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Does it reach the onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: Auth state listener is working perfectly on other activities on my app.But.,I am going to perform a verification operation on my app.so whenever user clicks on signin button, activity will goes to home,at the time listener works perfectly ie.,it will still continue on home activity or go to verify activity if not,it works.After app comes to verify activity and my client will verify the mail id.But,after all the app does not goes to userhome.that's my problem exactly...